# Embed Interop Type” property in VS 2008

Tags: vsto

does “Embed Interop Type” property exist in VS 2008 , and if not What is the alternative ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does “Embed Interop Type” property exist in VS 2008?

No. That's part of the C# 4.0 compiler which ships with Visual Studio 2010.

> If not What is the alternative ?

You can:

1. Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010.
2. Use the C# 4 compiler from the command line and the [/link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264728.aspx) switch.
3. Not use this feature and have interop assemblies.